# How to filter by date using select option in jquery Datatable

Tags: datepicker, datatables

[image]

I need to get the data based on the selected date and im using datatable

Here is my sample code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(tablename).dataTable({

        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        //"pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "info":     false,

        "sorting": [],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0,5,6 ],
                "sortable": false,

            },
        ]
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a ready solution for this case. I think you just need to pass some variable to the back-end through the searching textbox.

Comment: i just figure it out using jquery

Comment: Check out https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html